# How can I seal/close a head model at the bottom so no light will get in but only from the eyes?

Tags: modeling

The model I have is opened in the bottom and I want to seal/close it:

[image: Head]

What I tried:

Changed to edit mode then clicked on C then dragged and selected the vertices around the hole:

[image: Selected vertices]

Then I pressed once on F:
But still there is a hole:

[image: After pressed F didn't fill it all]

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with the effect of your Mirror modifier... by the way you should enable Clipping so that no vertice don't cross the axis line, and the Adjust Edit Cage button is grey, I don't know what it means. Maybe try to see if your problem comes from this modifier, also try to apply this modifier if you don't need it anymore, even if you should be able to close your hole without applying. You can share your file if you want us to test some solutions.

Comment: You are selecting more vertices than those at the edge of the neck, so that when you create a new face it connects all of the selected vertices in an unpredictable manner. Delete the newly created faces, deselect all (Press A) and select only the outermost edge of the neck. (Use Alt+Click to select the edge loop)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are not only selecting the vertices around the hole—only select the vertices that are actually "touching the hole" (if that makes sense). If it's still not working, it's likely you're having some sort of issue with the mirror modifier. Try applying the modifier, select all, and then W-->remove doubles. Select all of the vertices surrounding the hole, and then press "F." This should fill it up nicely.

Comment: I tried. Updated my question with what I tried and how but still there is a hole it didn't fill it all.

Comment: Updated the answer.